# Why I cannot do this in PHP

Tags: php, html

```
<?php 
if(isset($row['status']) AND 
  if($row['status']=="pending"))  
{ 
?>
<span class="pending">Pending</span>
<?php } ?>
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   T_IF in C:\Program
>   Files\EasyPHP-5.3.6.0\www\v0.3\view\friendships.php
>   on line 70

Comment: Mainly because PHP does not work like English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use AND

```
<?php 
  if(isset($row['status']) AND $row['status']=="pending")  : 
?>
   <span class="pending">Pending</span>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Remove the extra IF. And consider using alternative control structures, much easier to read when mixing HTML and PHP

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score 7):

Because that's not the way a condition is written, in PHP : you must put the conditional expression *(which can contain several sub-expressions, using `||` and/or `&&`)* between the parenthesis of the `if()` -- and not use two ifs :

```
if ( isset($row['status']) && $row['status']=="pending" ) {
   // do something
}
```

A couple of interesting sections of the manual, that you might want to read :

- [`if`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)
- [Expressions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php)
- [Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php) -- see also [Logical Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Comment: `and` can still be used in place of `&&`, the only difference is in operator precedence.

Answer (score 2):

You can't put an IF tag inside another IF tag. Rewrite it like this:

```
<?php if(isset($row['status']) && $row['status']=="pending")  { ?><span class="pending">Pending</span><? } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have extra if in your condition. It should be like this

```
<?php if(isset($row['status']) AND ($row['status']=="pending"))
```

You can't have another if statement in a if expression

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't nest an `if` statement within the condition of another `if` statement, as an `if` statement is a *statement* and not an *expression*, and an `if` statement only accepts *expressions*.

You probably just want this:

```
if (isset($row['status']) && $row['status'] == 'pending')
```